# How to insert image into database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to insert image into database table say ad_images
my table structure is
tblName : `ad_images`

```
Image_ID int PK 
Image LONGBLOB
Ad_ID int FK
SubCat_ID int FK
```

so how insert image into above table using codeigniter
thanx in advance

Comment: why you want to do this? you can only save your images path or name in table and access them by their path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid saving images and binary files to the database. Just save the path to the file in the database.

If you still want to to that:

Base64 encode(to avoid escaping, that may harm your data) the image data and put it into the field, like you would do with any other data.

```
 <?php

 $pathToImage = '/abc/img.jpg';

 // not sure about codeigniter syntax, but you should understand whatis meant. 
$table->image =
base64_encode(file_get_contents($pathToImage)); 
$table->save();
```

Don't forget to decode the data on your way back.

Ref:

[base64_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php)

[base64_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)